# ActiveRecord query grouping fails on 'id' field in order

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

This is an annoying case that keeps happening to me - I want understand why, and how to fix it once and for all.

I'm trying to get the amount of comments per posts, from a list of post ids. So at first I check that I got what I want, and it works great

> Comments.joins(:post).where('posts.id' =>
>   [123,147]).count

Now I want to group by the post.id:

> Comments.joins(:post).where('posts.id' =>
>   [123,147]).group('posts.id').count

And it fails on:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...e_id" IN (123, 147) GROUP BY posts.id ORDER BY id ASC
```

I realize that 'id' is ambiguous, but I didn't ask for an ordering, and when I try to add my own ordering, it just adds my ordering to the id - so it fails again! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer for another question, that helped.

Apparently, the Posts.rb file had this line:

```
default_scope { order('id ASC') }
```

Which caused it to add the 'id ASC' to the end of the query string. Removing it did the trick.